# Comparing the solutions to a multi-objective optimization problem

Tags: optimization, algorithms

Suppose I have a multi-objective optimization problem, and I wish to find solutions using two different methods/algorithms. The result of each algorithms is a Pareto front. Comparing two different methods for a single-objective optimization problem is simple: just see which one produces the better result for the single objective. However, for a multi-objective problem, one would need to compare the resulting Pareto fronts, supposedly.

My question then is: is it possible to compare two Pareto fronts? How would you say that one algorithm performs "better" than the other?

Thanks, and any insight is valued.